# How do I click on a particular cell with an specific text in a dynamic table

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing an automation script using Java and Selenium on a Windows environment.

I've got a table with many rows and 3 columns.
The information are unsorted and dynamically created.
I'm trying to click on a particular cell that has a specific text therein.
I've tried adapting the codes I found herein but none has worked.

I'm able to identify

1. I was able to identify the table.
2. I identified the row.

But unable to click the cell

```java
List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("tr"));

List<WebElement> tableCells= table.findElements(By.xpath("tr/td"));

for(WebElement cell : tableCells) {
    cell.click());
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_